# Send JSON Object with HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#

Well, I know that `HttpClient.SendAsync()` can be used to send `HttpRequestMessage` and request Method can be set to POST and Content to `StringContent` for simple string... but in my case i want to send a more complex `JSON` string which looks like this

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": ""
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "UNSPECIFIED",
          "maxResults": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use JavaScriptSerializer but don't know how to create an object that reprsents such json.

```
await Browser.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize())
});
```

Comment: That is already json, you can't serialize it any further. Just use the json as the `StringContent`.

Comment: @Crowcoder Can i create a class that represents this tree ? if so what should it look like ?, i don't wanna serialize this string i wanna create one on demand that looks like this

Comment: Create a class, which has a structure like that. Fill it. Serialize it as string. Then send it through HttpClient.

Comment: If you create a class you can let an extension of HttpClient handle the serialization for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx'

Comment: @Crowcoder What the class should look like to be serialized into this format ?, can you provide an answer with a class ?

Comment: Copy your json to the clipboard, create a class stub in visual studio, then go to Edit, paste special, paste json as classes and it will build it for you.

Comment: @Crowcoder never heard of Class Stub how do i access it ?

Comment: I just mean add a new class to your project just so you have a place to paste. You can use an existing file too, whatever is convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the C# code for this object, use the RootObject class

```
public class Image
{
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public Image image { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Request> requests { get; set; }
}
```

Provided courtesy of http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I always try to take the lazy road ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create classes as @x... pointed in the comment in order to build your tree

```
public class features
{
   public string type {get;set;}
   public int maxResults {get;set;}
}
public class requests 
{
   public List<features> {get;set;}
   ... the same for images
}
```

Populate it, serialize it and send the request...